# Update one DLL file in an ASP.NET website project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, dll

net development. I am working in a website project and I am trying to update one of the dll files. I've search for hours for a solution on stackoverflow, but no luck.

Our website project in Visual studios is composed of one website that uses three C# projects. I am trying to update just one of these C# projects. Currently the website is in production and the DLL files of these projects are in the /bin folder.

1. I opened up the solution in VS and made my changes.
2. I built the whole solution and retrieved the new dll.
3. I stopped our in-process website with IIS and overwrote the dll and restarted it again.

I get an Missing Method Exception as an error when I do this. I was hoping for a straight forward way of updating our website project because I only need to change about two lines of code and swapping dll files seems like the easiest way of doing this.

Thank you guys for your help and be patient with me I am a slow learner and I ask a lot of questions.

Comment: I've experienced problems when trying to update just one of the files; can you update all of the code via copy and paste to the server, and see if you still get the error?

Comment: Like instead of uploading just one dll file, I just swap out everything in the bin folder with the newly built project?

Comment: Basically copy over all the DLL's and web files over the existing project.  This is normally how I do deployments, and it's worked for me.

Comment: In the project that you are changing, because it seems that it is being referenced and used by the main web dll, if you change a method signature or remove a method, you will not get away by only changing the one dll. for example if the dll contains a method called GetUser(int id) and you change that method to, GetUser(string id), the web application will no longer work if it us using that method. From you error that you wrote, it seems that it cannot find a method that it is expecting to be there.

Comment: BTW, changing DLL dependency in BIN should restart the application. But sometimes you need to stop the pool to release the DLL. You definitely messed up some method signature. If you don't think, this is the case, try to remove Asp.net cache

Comment: one of the reasons I'm starting to hate ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason of this to occur could be that your dll is built using different version of .net framework than what is on your server. You can check that and see if that resolves the issue.